# If $G$ is compact and $K \subset G$ is closed in $G$, must $G/K$ also be compact?

Tags: general-topology

If $G$ is compact and $K \subset G$ is closed in $G$, must $G/K$ also be compact?

The sets $G$ is a topological group for example.

Comment: As @TsemoAristide's answer notes, a continuous image of a compact topological space is always compact. It doesn't even matter whether or not $K$ is closed in your example, although it is true that if it is _not_ closed the quotient will not be Hausdorff. But that doesn't actually impede compactness, it just makes other details less intuitive (to my perception).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is compact if it is endowed with the quotient topology since it is the image of the compact $G$ by the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/K$ and the image of a compact by a continue map is compact.

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but I remembered the quotient map is surjective. Where does it preserve the topological property (compactness) here? Continuity of the quotient map?

Comment: The image of a compact by a continue map is compact, so since $G$ is compact, $p(G)=G/K$ is compact where $p:G\rightarrow G/K$ is the quotient map  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

Comment: Continuous maps in topology preserves topological properties right? That appears to be encoded in the definition of continuity in some texts